# Web search indexing for "highest voted questions" "newest questions" etc pages

Tags: feature-request

Oftentimes, when I search for something on Google that hits stackoverflow, I see the "highest voted XYZ questions", "newest XYZ questions" and other such pages showing up in results.

Example: search `connection closed eof detected`

The content in these pages is very ephemeral, and being list pages that merely link to questions, they don't have much value as web search results in my opinion.

Maybe we should consider hiding these pages from the web search bots?

Comment: I've never seen any of these in my Google search results. Can you name some search terms that will give these as a result?

Comment: @funie200 I just searched for "connection closed eof detected" (an error message) and the 6th SO result is "Highest voted ..."

Comment: I see the google search results aspect of SO as central to the site's main goal. I thought that was intended and even the main purpose of SO, but maybe I am wrong.